# Apply javascript function to an html element

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

Sorry for the noob question but I am trying to apply this javascript function to data in an html table. The function comes from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript).

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

I wish to apply this function to something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>5000</td>
        <td>5600</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with the hopes of returning 5,000 next to 5,600.  I can't figure out this simple thing.  I know I need to use an id or class on one of the tags and that this needs to match something in the function so I tried

```
<table>
    <tr class="numberWithCommas">
        <td>5000</td>
        <td>5600</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

to no avail.  I'm sure the function works given the amount of upvotes.

Can a kind soul please walk me through the steps to make this work?  I've googled all over for a basic tutorial and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to get all the `td`s, call the function on the content and insert the result back into the cell.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class="numberWithCommas">
        <td>5000</td>
        <td>5600</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.numberWithCommas td'),
    i;

for (i in elements) {
    if (elements[i].innerHTML !== undefined) {
        elements[i].innerHTML = numberWithCommas(elements[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mvweD/4/)**

To explain all this code:

This is your function:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

This allows us to get all the `td` within all `tr`s with `numberWithCommas` as a class and sets them all as an array in the javascript variable `elements`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.numberWithCommas td'),
    i;
```

We then loop through the array accessing one `td` at a time:

```
for (i in elements) {
    ...
}
```

Inside the for loop we check that the value of the cell is not empty:

```
if (elements[i].innerHTML !== undefined) {
    ...
}
```

Inside the `if` statement we call the function `numberWithCommas()` and pass it the value of `elements[i].innerHTML`. We then get back the resulting string and apply it to `elements[i].innerHTML`:

```
elements[i].innerHTML = numberWithCommas(elements[i].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over `each td` and apply this function..

```
var tr = document.getElementsByClassName('numberWithCommas');

for (var i = 0, len = tr.length; i < len; i++) {
    for(var j=0,len1 = tr[i].children.length;j<len1; j++){
        var td = tr[i].children[j];
        td.innerHTML= numberWithCommas(td.innerHTML)
    }
}​

function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Npac8/1/)**

Using jQuery

```
$('table tr.numberWithCommas').each(function(){
    var $tr = $(this);
    $tr.find('td').each(function(){
        var $td = $(this);
        $td.html(function(){
            return  numberWithCommas(this.innerHTML);
        });
    });        
});
```

**[jQuery Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/uNwea/)**

Comment: What do you mean by that ??

Comment: @gibberish the code runs automatically. If he wanted a trigger for it, he could put it in its own function and call it.